# How do I pass the column names for a jQuery data table from a JSON file?

Tags: json

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $('#employeeDetails').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[5,10 , 15, -1], [5, 10, 15, "All"]],
    "ajax": "employeeDetails.json",

    "aoColumns": [{
      "mData": "name" 
    },{
      "mData": "age"
    },{
      "mData":"designation"
    },{
      "mData": "salary"
    }]
  });
});
```

and HTML is

```
<table id="employeeDetails">

</table>
```

How can I get the column header from a separate JSON file?

Comment: see this http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2529/column-definition-via-json-array-ajax/p1

Comment: How can I changed my code?Can you please help me.

Comment: try to get this part dynamically by some ajax call and use it.some thing like this: var data = [{
      "mData": "name" 
    },{
      "mData": "age"
    },{
      "mData":"designation"
    },{
      "mData": "salary"
    }]// from ajax response. then "aoColumns": data